# kth permutation using factoradic

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, permutation

I want to find kth permutation of numbers from 1 to n for large values of k.
I found out a method called factoradic of a number but I am not able to implement it.
Any other method will also be useful.
Can anyone help?

Comment: which programming language do u wanna use ?

Comment: I want to C language

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of white paper and wikipedia reading I ended up with this (NB: Permutation is 0 based not 1 based)

Test Code

```
    [Test]
    public void Permutation_0_Returns_0123456789()
    {
        int[] factoradic = 0.ToFactoradic(10);
        int[] permutation = factoradic.ToPermutation(10);
        int[] expected = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, permutation);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Permutation_1_Returns_0123456798()
    {
        int[] factoradic = 1.ToFactoradic(10);
        int[] permutation = factoradic.ToPermutation(10);
        int[] expected = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8 };
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, permutation);
    }
```

Implementation

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system
    public static int[] ToFactoradic(this int value, int digitCount)
    {
        var factoradic = new int[digitCount];
        //Repeatedly divide by an increasing number
        //The reverse of the remainders forms the factoradic
        for (var i = 1; i <= digitCount; i++)
        {
            factoradic[digitCount - i] = value % i;
            value /= i;
        }
        return factoradic;
    }

    public static int[] ToPermutation(this int[] value, int digitCount)
    {
        //Initialise the digit list
        var digitList = new List<int>(digitCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < digitCount; i++)
        {
            digitList.Add(i);
        }
        //Loop through the factoradic pulling out each value in turn
        // Use this value as an index into the digit list removing each digit as it's used
        var permutationList = new List<int>(digitCount);
        for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            int indexIntoDigitList = value[i];
            int atom = digitList[indexIntoDigitList];
            digitList.RemoveAt(indexIntoDigitList);
            permutationList.Add(atom);
        }

        return permutationList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Microsoft article with a C# implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163513.aspx

Edit: here's a paste of the juicy bit (apologies for lack of formatting - that's how it is in the source article)

```
public StringPerm(string[] atoms, int k) 
{
    this.element = new string[atoms.Length]; 
    this.order = atoms.Length; 

    // Step #1 - Find factoradic of k 
    int[] factoradic = new int[this.order]; 
    for (int j = 1; j <= this.order; ++j) 
    { 
        factoradic[this.order - j] = k % j; 
        k /= j; 
    } 

    // Step #2 - Convert factoradic[] to numeric permuatation in perm[] 
    int[] temp = new int[this.order]; 
    int[] perm = new int[this.order]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < this.order; ++i) 
    {
         temp[i] = ++factoradic[i]; 
    }
    perm[this.order - 1] = 1; 
    // right-most value is set to 1. 

    for (int i = this.order - 2; i >= 0; --i) 
    {
        perm[i] = temp[i]; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < this.order; ++j) 
        {
            if (perm[j] >= perm[i]) 
            ++perm[j]; 
        }
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < this.order; ++i) // put in 0-based form 
        --perm[i];

    // Step #3 - map numeric permutation to string permutation 
    for (int i = 0; i < this.order; ++i) 
        this.element[i] = atoms[perm[i]]; 
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The MSDN magazine article link has (unsurprisingly) moved. Note, this article is in the July 2004 issue and the main MSDN magazine link is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues.aspx. The issue can be downloaded from the following link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineJuly2004en-us.chm. The article is called "Test Run".

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String nextPermutationSequence(int N, int k){

        int nMinusOneFactorial = 1;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
            list.add(i);
            nMinusOneFactorial*=i;
        }

        k=k-1;
        nMinusOneFactorial=nMinusOneFactorial/N;

        for(int i=N-1;i>=1;i--){

            int position = k/nMinusOneFactorial;
            int val = list.get(position);
            buf.append(Integer.valueOf(val));
            list.remove(position);
            k = k%nMinusOneFactorial;
            nMinusOneFactorial=nMinusOneFactorial/i;

        }

        buf.append(Integer.valueOf(list.get(0)));
        return buf.toString();
    }
```